# Can't boot FreeBSD after successful installation

Tags: freebsd

I've installed Slackware 14.2 in /dev/sda1 and x86Solaris 10 U6 in /dev/sda3 (sda2 is Linux swap)and boot menu was Solaris grub but, later deleted Solaris partition and installed FreeBSD12 (for i386) on the same partition.

I created separate partitions for /boot (1G), / (1G), /var (2G), /tmp (1G), swap (3G) and / (23G) in FreeBSD and the installation was seemed to be OK as there was no error msg.

But FreeBSD couldn't boot so I had to use Slack's installation disc to boot slack and used **lilo -v** to add slack in lilo table. Here lilo throws the following errors:

```
Warning: LBA32 addressing assumed
Reading boot sector from /dev/sda1
Using BITMAP secondary loader
Calling map_insert_data
Mapping bitmap file /boot/slack.bmp
Calling map_insert_file

Boot image: /boot/vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-huge-smp-4.4.172-smp
Added Linux  *

Boot other: /dev/sda3, on /dev/sda, loader CHAIN
Added FreeBSD

Writing boot sector.
/boot/boot.0801 exists - no boot sector backup copy made.
One warning was issued.
```

I also make **/dev/sda1** as active in lilo using fdisk with a command. Now there are two partitions are marked active, /dev/sda1 for slack and /dev/sda3 for FreeBSD.

In lilo boot menu the following error message appears when **FreeBSD** is selected.

```
FreeBSD/x86 boot
Default: 0:ad(0,a)/boot/loader
boot: loader: not a config directory  

FreeBSD/x86 boot
Default: 0:ad(0,a)/boot/loader
boot: _ <*here cursor blinks*>
```

I think it comes from a leftover of Solaris' grub but I'm not sure.

Here is the **lilo.conf** entry for slack and freebsd:

```
# Linux bootable partition config begins
image = /boot/vmlinuz
  root = /dev/sda1
  label = Linux
  read-only
# Linux bootable partition config ends
  other=/dev/sda3
    table=/dev/sda
    label=FreeBSD
```

I use 486 with 1.5G memory and 180G ide type HDD.

How will I be able to boot FreeBSD?